# Flash button that links to PDF

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, flash-cs4

I'm trying to create a button in Flash CS4 with Actionscript3 that links to a PDF file but when I publish the link just takes me to www.example.com

I have other links that are working to external sites just this PDF button doesn't work, any ideas would most appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
var pdfURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.arrowecs.co.uk/downloads/SecuringVirtualizedDatacenters_ebook.pdf");


//PDF Link
function pdfLink(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(pdfURL,"_self");
}

download_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pdfLink);
```

Thanks

Giles

Comment: Does it really take you to www.example.com ?

Comment: ??? Yes.

I fixed it in the end by restarting flash, its such a buggy program. No wonder Apple want to get rid of it!